# how to embed C# code in 89c51 microcontroller

Tags: c#, embedded, .net-assembly

I am dealing with a project related to Embedded System.
I want my controller(89c51 micro-controller) to respond(do the programmed actions) when I'll click on a button(GUI designed in .NET technology). Tell me programming language to write code for controller.
What should I do for, 'my hardware-part to respond according to click event on GUI/Button (Designed in .NET)
Also tell me the supposed steps(for compiling & burning code on Controller) so that I could communicate with the micro-controller on an event. I'll also like to know the necessary tools that I must have, if any.
Thank you.

Comment: Your questions is really broad and hard to answer in a definitive way. Could you edit it and ask one, more specific, question?

Comment: Is this a controller that runs the micro framework?

Comment: I doubt it. My guess is, that he is refering to the classes he needs to open a serial connection to the AT89C51 (a µC that comes with a serial interface)

Comment: Not possible AFAIK, if you must use embedded c# then you need to use a devboard/cpu thats compatible with the .net microframework http://www.netmf.com/ otherwise port to C or ASM and use your tool chain of choice for embedded work

Comment: The uC in question is probably underpowered for most modern washing machines, let alone running any kind of language run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are asking about how to establish a connection to the [AT89C51](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0265.pdf) (click for data sheet).

The AT89C51 seems to come with a serial port on Port 3. You will need C to program the micro-controller itself, but can establish a serial connection to Port 3 using C#.

See this class for reference and examples on how to establish a serial connection using C#: [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)

Comment: That's actually an interesting thought... the whole question would be a bit weird then, though.

Comment: @Mario Yeah. But given that he has just one rep (i.e. a new user), I assume that he is still struckling with expressing his ideas. Just like me at that time - or even today

Comment: While there are C compilers for the 80x51 family, there's often some wisdom in using assembly on chips that small.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Agreed on principal. However, he was trying to run C# on that darn thing, no need to confuse him further.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with an 89C51 as its only an 8bit processor.

If you want to run embedded C# you need something like a netduino or GHI fez board, which are low cost .net micro framework development boards.

If the question is asking how to connect to the MCU via C# then as stated program MCU to enable serial functionality, then write in C# a serial application using the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class.

Comment: Technically, the "not possible" is due to insufficient memory, not the 8-bit processor.  Given enough memory (explicitly paged), the most primitive CPU can do anything the latest multi-core workstation can... it will just take a year.

Comment: True anything is possible, just not particuarly workable, http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/124287-the-worlds-slowest-linux-pc <-- linux running on an ATmega1284p

Comment: Nice example of exactly what I meant!

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, because you can't (with common compilers) compile C# into native code the embedded system understands. C# compiles to an intermediate code (MSIL/CIL), that is then compiled/executed by the runtime environment (which you won't have in most embedded system).

When programming for real-time embedded systems, there's usually no way around assembly (or C/C++ if you're lucky) unless your platform explicitly supports/is based on the .NET Micro Framework, which will also only support a specific subset of the whole .NET runtime available on desktop machines

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that after writing - updating.

Comment: @Mario: You're right, it doesn't matter if it is .Net , Compact .Net or micro .Net frameworks, C# compiles to intermediate code. If a controller can't support a .Net framework, it can't run C# code.

Comment: C is almost entirely ubiquitous and C++ only slightly less so (being less useful on very constrained 8 bit targets).  You don't have to get "lucky" to use C on embedded systems; very few I would suggest are in fact programmed in  assembler these days.